# Passing data between different PHP instances

Tags: php, asynchronous, communication, reactphp

index.php is parsed by Apache.  It needs to pass some data to another PHP instance which happens to be a reactphp loop.  How can this be best accomplished?  Both scripts are run on the same machine.

```
<?php
//index.php
$status=sendDataToOtherInstance('hello'); //blocking function which returns true/false
```

.

```
<?php

//reactphp loop

$foo->on('connection', function ($data){
    echo($data);
    return $data==='hello';
});
```

Comment: Another PHP instance?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  How can I better describe this.  I have two instances of PHP running, and data must go from one to the other.

Comment: On another server? In another partition?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  Sorry, I wasn't clear.  Both the same server.  I updated the original post.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is put a HTTP server in the reactphp loop, and have index.php send a curl request to it.  Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: If you have 2 scripts running on the same machine (under the same server) you could use cURL or websockets.

Comment: Is second page supposed to be make responses just for index.php ?

Comment: The second page is a sockets server which provides asynchronous communication to various remote clients.  index.php needs to inject data which gets sent to those remote clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few options:

1. HTTP between the 2 processes

   Like you say this is a bit messy, not too bad, it will be quick, but a little messy.
2. Unix socket file

   Only problem is `reactphp` doesn't work with unix sockets at the minute.

   More info: https://github.com/reactphp/socket/pull/17
3. TCP Socket

   This should work. But just as clunky as the 1st option.

To be honest it sounds like your getting to the limits of php.

**Node.js**

I'm not sure if you've ever used it, but `node.js` was made for this sort of task. And allows lots of functionality php does not.

https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of inter-process communication.

You can do it with IPC (of course); using shared memory. Or with slightly worse performances, but IMHO better manageability, using a temporary file on a RAM disk or temporary file system. Of course IPC also gives you the ability of waiting on semaphored resources, which may come handy and improve responsiveness (you could have the same by opening a socket, or a full HTTP server, in the reactphp process).

You could also do this by leveraging external applications (e.g. some *MQ, or Redis).

If you have a database such as MySQL, you can have the two processes "communicate" through a shared table.

Answer (score 0):

As `LSemi` said you can do it using shared memory or basically you already got a WebSocket server Why don't you get responses with PHP WebSocket Client library ?

https://github.com/Textalk/websocket-php